# Can not rename a single file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to rename a file in downloads folder and I get (I translate)

```
OSError: [WinError 123] Syntax of filename, catalog name or label is wrong: 'C:\\Users\\Miaoulis\\Downloads\\feed.xml' -> 'C:\\Users\\Miaoulis\\Downloads\\VECTOR_03-10-2020 16:49_new.xml'
```

using windows 10, Kaspersky Internet Security and the following

```
import os

src = 'C:\\Users\\Miaoulis\\Downloads\\feed.xml'
dst = 'C:\\Users\\Miaoulis\\Downloads\\VECTOR_'+str(file_date)+'_new.xml'
if os.path.isfile(src):
   os.rename(src, dst)
```

thank you

Comment: Try removing/replacing the colon : in file_date.

Comment: together with C?

Comment: Just in file_date

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), colons are not allowed in file names.

Comment: And use something like today.strftime("%m/%d/%y") ?

Comment: Not the colon after `C` - the one in the date string - `03-10-2020 16:49`. You need to remove that. To be honest, I'd replace the space between date and time with an underscore as well.

Comment: Ok Thank you its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination file name has a colon.  Try renaming without colon.